# Is the position vector an axial vector?

Tags: angular-momentum, vectors, definition, torque, displacement

The displacement vector $\vec{r}_{ij} = \vec{r}_j - \vec{r}_i$ is of course a polar vector because it's completely independent of the choice of origin, but what about the position $\vec{r}$ which, by definition, both magnitude and direction depends on the choice of origin?

For the magnetic field $\vec{B}$, which is a pseudovector, we have the Biot-Savart law in the form:

$$\vec{B} = \dfrac{\mu_0 I}{4\pi}\int \dfrac{\vec{dl} \times \vec{r'}}{(r')^3}$$

Where $\vec{r'}$ is a displacement vector between an arbitrary charge and the point where the field is being measured and $\vec{dl}$ is also an actual vector. However, for angular momentum $\vec{l}$ and torque $\vec{\tau}$, the formulas are:

$$\vec{l} = \vec{r} \times \vec{p}$$ and $$\vec{\tau} = \dfrac{d \vec{l}}{dt} = \vec{r} \times \vec{F}$$

Where $\vec{r}$ is a position vector with respect to a chosen origin. The definition for cross products and pseudovectors, at least according to Wikipedia, are:

- Pseudovector = Pseudovector $\times$ Pseudovector
- Pseudovector = Vector $\times$ Vector
- Vector = Vector $\times$ Pseudovector (and the inverse order as well)

If $\vec{l}$ and $\vec{\tau}$ are pseudovectors because they are origin dependent, that implies that the position $\vec{r}$ should be a vector from the rules above, because $\vec{F}$ and $\vec{p}$ are both vectors.

Now, if one of the requirements to be defined as a pseudovector is to be origin dependent, then one of the following should be wrong:

- The position vector $\vec{r}$ is a polar vector;
- The rules about vectors, pseudovectors and cross product.

Either this or the that shouldn't be the definition of pseudovectors. So, where do I understand it wrongly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Now, if one of the requirements to be defined as a pseudovector is to be origin dependent

This is false.

> For the magnetic field $\vec B$, which is a pseudovector, we have the Biot-Savart law

That definition is correctly origin independent.

---

You are not allowed to add and subtract vectors and pseudovectors. By this simple rule, it is clear that if displacement vectors are vectors, then position also has to be a vector.

---

In better maths, you will learn that position and displacement are not vectors, because when spacetime is curved, you can no longer sensibly define these things. Instead, you get to lay down coördinates as you like, and use differentiation to define velocity vectors.

In other better maths too, you can learn that there are just no such thing as axial or pseudovectors. It is an oddity of 3 and 7 dimensions that we can even play this stupid game. Instead, the pseudovectors that you are familiar with, are just bivectors rather than vectors. Rotation, in particular, is about a plane, not a single vector.